# How to avoid null checking - OOP

Tags: java, oop

I am making a game and I have a Tile class that contains an Item.

```
public clas Tile{
    Item item;
    ....
    public void setItem(Item item){
         this.item = item;
    }

}
```

When I have a reference to the Tile I want to call the `interact()` method on the item. How can I do this without checking if the object is `null`. I don't think the `Null` Object pattern will work in this scenario because there will be mixed instance cohesion - a subclass of item that would represent an empty item would have an empty `interact()` method.

Comment: I don't understand your reason for not using the null object pattern. A null object is *supposed* to be non-reactive, or at least reasonable, across its interface. In any case, unless you have a flag that indicates if the tile has an item (basically duplicating item null-ness) I don't see what the other options would be. I guess I don't understand what's wrong with a `NoItem` item.

Comment: Because it's mixed instance cohesion

Comment: ... Then check for null. I think you're being overly pedantic, since this would be true for *any* null object (which I view as a special case anyway). A null object *by definition* won't implement most functionality of a non-null implementation.

Comment: I think I may be overly pedantic...

Comment: every object will have multiple sub-objects . now every method might not need all the objects . -----------if tile is a board game , then u dont need to bother of attributes like color/colour . at every function which can crash on nulls , just check for required member fields and not title as a whole .

Comment: Will the game ever have more than 1 item per tile?

Comment: No it will always have a maximum of one

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find a way to not check if the object is null, when null is an option.

In this case, design to check if `item != null`, before execute `item.interact()`, is not an anti-pattern or hacking solution.

Answer (score 0):

The stereotypical solution to the mixed instance cohesion problem is to create subclasses (and make sure that the superclass doesn't expose the subclass-specific functionality).

So you create a `ItemTile` and `NonItemTile` subclass of `Tile`.

```
public abstract class Tile {
    public abstract void interact();
}

public class ItemTile extends Tile {
    private final Item item;
    ....
    public ItemTile(Item item) {
        // Null-check to enforce contract - could be omitted if you make this
        // the responsibility of the caller.
        if (item == null)
           throw new NullPointerException("item");
        this.item = item;
    }

    public void interact() {
        item.interact();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this would work because an item can be picked up and that would break the contract for ItemTile

Comment: That sounds relevant. You should put that in the question so people can take that into account when answering the question